# Can't create ListView.builder with a list

Tags: list, flutter, listview, dart

I tried to build a ListView.builder with a List.

It Shows me this Error: **The argument type 'CartItem' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'**

Here is my code:

```
class CartItem {
  String name;
  String quantity;
  String price;

  CartItem({
    this.name,
    this.quantity,
    this.price,
  });
}

List<CartItem> cartItem = [];

var _quantity = TextEditingController();

Widget cartList() {
  if (cartItem.length != 0) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cartItem.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(cartItem[index]);
      },
    );
  }
  return Text('Nothing in Cart');
}
```

And here is the implementation of my widget method:

```
RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 1,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext contex) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            content: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text('Your Order List'),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: cartList(),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Conferm Order',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` widget required `String` as an argument while `cartItem[index]` returned the instance of `CartItem` that's why you are getting an error

You should use

```
return Text(cartItem[index].name);
```

instead of this

```
return Text(cartItem[index]);
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Widget cartList() {
  if (cartItem.length != 0) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cartItem.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(cartItem[index].name);
      },
    );
  }
  return Text('Nothing in Cart');
}
```

Comment: Your Answer is correct but I fatch another problem with my widget method. it show me an error: `Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
file:~/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tra
cking.dart:392:12`

Comment: @SantoShakil try to restart your app

Comment: it doesn't work. I think this is another issue. but your answer is correct for my question of this post. Thank you so much.